# ListPreference - Custom items possible?

Tags: android, listpreference

I'm trying to add an image / icon to certain entries of a ListPreference alongside the text.

**I would like achieve this programmatically**.

Here's an excerpt of the preferences.xml

```
<ListPreference
  android:key="prefGameMode"
  android:title="@string/pref_game_mode"
  android:summary="@string/pref_game_mode_desc"
  android:defaultValue="fourChallenge"
  android:entries="@array/arrGameMode"
  android:entryValues="@array/arrGameModeValues" 
  android:negativeButtonText="@string/cancel" />
...
```

The goal here is to illustrate that some of the options listed are unavailable/ locked in the current version of the app.  However, the code-base is used as a library, so I would like the solution to work via code, rather than xml.

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom row in a listPreference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549746/custom-row-in-a-listpreference)

Answer (score 0):

Preferences already gives you a way to indicate that an option is unavailable: just set [enabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3aenabled) properly.

Comment: Hi Mayra, I actually want modify individual entries of the list preference, not the actual Preference itself. I want to keep everything enabled because the '_locked_' options trigger the creation of a new intent.