# Adding listeners to individual ListPreference items

Tags: android, listener, android-preferences, event-listener

I'm trying to add individual listeners to items in a `ListPreference` but I just can't find the right code to do it.

For example, assume I have an app where needs the *region*  to be set. So I have a `ListPreference` with three options; Americas, Asia, Europe.

When I use the trackpad to scroll through the items I would like them to speak the text of the preference when they get focus.

I'm sure somewhere in the API I can add a listener to the individual items but I just can not find it.
There is a `setOnPreferenceClickListener(..)` method in `ListPreference` (inherited from `DialogPreference`) but that is for when you select the actual parent preference item.

Do I need to write a special subclass?

**EDIT**

After looking into this more I think I need to further clarify my question.
When using preferences you can override the `onPreferenceTreeClick (PreferenceScreen prefScreen, Preference pref)` method in the `PreferenceActivity`. This allows you to intercept any clicks on preferences. However I want to add a listener to the actual dialog that pops up. The "Americas, Asia, Europe" options from the above example. So if I select or click on Asia I can intercept it.

So my (refined) question is how can add a listener to those individual options.

cheers

Answer (score 10):

```
final ListPreference list = (ListPreference) preference;
list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        int index = list.findIndexOfValue(newValue.toString());

        if (index != -1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.getEntries()[index], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem all the time. if user clicked on the default item this on change listener won't be called.

Answer (score 2):

OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is called when persistent = true after the sharedPref value was changed, but for each item you can actually assign its own OnPreferenceChangeListener and there you see which item was clicked

```
ListPreference pLocAuto = (ListPreference) findPreference(PREF_LOC_AUTO);
pUpdateAuto.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                System.out.print(newValue.toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It helped, but it shall return TRUE if you want it to be saved after change.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's another post on stackoverflow that is similar to this one: [Custom Row in a ListPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549746/custom-row-in-a-listpreference).

In this one, subclassing is the solution. But may be in your case you can use a simple [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

If you have set up the adapter, you can use the method `onItemClick` and inside the method you can use a `switch` statement (`case` is the id or the index in an array or anything like this) to call different methods.

I hope I understood your question... :)

Ah! You also need to have a look on the [`onFocusChange` Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html). You can add this Listener to every Preference Item (which has to be a View; you add the listener in the adapter), then in the listener method have the announced switch statement.

Greetings and i hope i could provide you a hint,

Julian

Comment: Thanks Julian. I'm looking at that now. I'm still trying to get my head around `PreferenceScreen`, `ListPreference`, `ListView`, `ListAdapter` and how they all fit together. I basically need to get a reference to the `ListView` of my `ListPreference`. Is there a way to get a reference to a `ListPreference` (like the way you can do a `findViewByID(R.id.my_button)` )?