# Button in a listview with holder pattern

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I have a listview that contains a botton in each row.

The button open a dialog for single value choice when clicked.

The thing is when I move down the list, values in the buttons are moving.
The first value is repeated each 8 rows.

Here is my getView() Code :

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public Button listaCerrada;
}


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_form, null);

            holder.listaCerrada = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listaCerrada);
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.listaCerrada.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get list Values
                String datoValido = metrica.getlForms().get(position)
                        .getProducto().getDatoValido();
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                // HAY:HAY;NO HAY:NO HAY
                String[] parts = datoValido.split(";");
                ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String s : parts) {
                    String[] part2 = s.split(":");
                    values.add(part2[0]);
                }

                final CharSequence[] items = values
                        .toArray(new CharSequence[values.size()]);

                adb.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                holder.listaCerrada.setText(items[which]);
                            }

                        });
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);


                adb.show();

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Android recycles views as you scroll to save memory.  Rather than using convertView, create a new view  View v = vi.inflate(...).

Comment: Using convertview is to get better performance. It should have a way to fix it without creating a view in each row. Otherwise, my list will not be fluid.

Comment: Have you implemented getItemType()?  Here's an answer with a lot of good information about correctly implementing a custom ListView adapter.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712494/getview-called-with-wrong-position-when-scrolling-fast

Comment: Tx for the link, it is very useful, but I understand getItemType applies when I have different layouts for each cell. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think what you essentially have to do is reset customView before you use it.  That way you know that the data previously held (if any) is cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since views are recycled, only set the OnClickListener when convertView == null. See the following updated code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    try {
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_lista_form, null);

            holder.listaCerrada = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listaCerrada);
            }

            holder.listaCerrada.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Get list Values
                  String datoValido = metrica.getlForms().get(position)
                        .getProducto().getDatoValido();
                  AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                  // HAY:HAY;NO HAY:NO HAY
                  String[] parts = datoValido.split(";");
                  ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                  for (String s : parts) {
                     String[] part2 = s.split(":");
                     values.add(part2[0]);
                  }

                  final CharSequence[] items = values
                        .toArray(new CharSequence[values.size()]);

                  adb.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                  int which) {
                               dialog.dismiss();

                               holder.listaCerrada.setText(items[which]);
                            }

                        });
                  adb.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);


                  adb.show();

               }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: The position variable in getView() contains the position information requested by the control to display stuff. When the user interact with the button on a row, the getView() doesn't get called. Therefore, save the position value in your ViewHolder object and set the value `holder.pos = position;` outside the if(convertView == null) block. Use `holder.pos` in your OnClickListener instead of `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution found with this page : http://blog.mettletech.co/wp/blog/settag-and-gettag-on-listview/

```
if (convertView == null) {
...
}else{
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 // ADD THIS
        Formulario f = lForm.get(position);
        String cantidad = f.getCantidad();
        holder.listaCerrada.setText(cantidad);


}
```