# Custom ListPreference RadioButton doesn't save selected Item

Tags: android

I'm building a project based on the existing SO question [custom row in a listPreference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549746/custom-row-in-a-listpreference). In my version of the program, selecting radio buttons does not work; the last checked item doesn't get saved. My simulated project is [here](http://s1.picofile.com/file/7491144301/CustomListPreferenceComponent.rar.html), and has a black background.

Comment: What about your code ? should we guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do these changes(part of codes):

```
public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        for(RadioButton rb : rButtonList)
                        {
                            if(rb.getId() != position)
                                rb.setChecked(false);
                        }

                        int index = position;
                        String value = entryValues[index].toString();
                        editor.putString("yourPref", value);
                        editor.commit();
                        Dialog mDialog = getDialog();
                        mDialog.dismiss();
```

---

```
CustomHolder(View row, int position)
        {    
            text = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view_row_text_view);
            text.setText(entries[position]);
       rButton =(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view_row_radio_button);
            rButton.setId(position);

            if(entryValues[position].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(FontSize))
            {
                rButton.setChecked(true);
            }
```

---

```
if(isChecked)
                    {
                        for(RadioButton rb : rButtonList)
                        {
                            if(rb != buttonView)
                                rb.setChecked(false);
                        }

                        int index = buttonView.getId();
                        String value = entryValues[index].toString();
                        editor.putString("yourPref", value);
                        editor.commit();
```

and FontSize variable fill in constructor:

```
SharedPreferences fontsizesetting = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String temp = fontsizesetting.getString("yourPref","16");
```

Comment: Hey, If I am implementing it for more than one listPreferences, how can I get the `"key"` as here it is hard coded as `"yourPref"`?