# Border and separator color of a dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create a dialog containing SingleChoiceItems but with orange border and separator color, like the view below.

[image]

Here are my dialog code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(GameDetailsScreen.this)
.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

}
})
.create().show();
```

How can i set the separator color of my dialog and the border color.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own style for the dialogs. Check out these links:
[attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs)!
[styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)!
[custom listpreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549746/custom-row-in-a-listpreference)!
It requires a lot of work, but worth it to learn.