# Style a Dialog in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to change the style of the Dialogs appearing in a PreferenceFragment.

My PreferenceFragment.java file:

```
public class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment  {

    public PreferencesFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

the preferences.xml file:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preferences_category_general_title">

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="en"
            android:entries="@array/preferences_languages"
            android:entryValues="@array/preferences_languages_values"
            android:key="language"
            android:title="@string/preferences_languages_title" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want the dialog of a e.g. ListPreference look like this:

[image: DialogPreference with custom Style]

Currently they have the default Holo style, how do I change it? (I only want the custom title bar, the radio buttons aren't important)

Answer (score 1):

Android handles the preference stuff on its own. 
However, you can extend `ListPreference` and override `showDialog(Bundle b)`  method. Then you can show your custom dialog in there. 
For a sample see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27429926/3080611)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**onPrepareDialogBuilder**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onPrepareDialogBuilder(android.app.AlertDialog.Builder)) method from the ListPrefrence.