# MaterialAlertDialogBuilder for DialogPreferences in PreferenceFragments

Tags: material-design, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In preference screens, I'd like to use MaterialComponent's dialogs (using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`) instead of `AlertDialog` from AppCompat. However, AppCompat's preference framework hardcodes using the `AlertDialog.Builder`.

From what I can see, the only way to override this is to override: [`PreferenceFragmentCompat.onDisplayPreferenceDialog()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat#onDisplayPreferenceDialog(androidx.preference.Preference)) and copy a bunch of the logic from that superclass (in terms of showing the dialog fragment etc).

Is this the correct approach or is there a better way?

Comment: How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution for `ListPreference`:

```kotlin
class MaterialListPreferenceDialogFragment : ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val context: Context? = activity
        mWhichButtonClicked = DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE
        val builder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireActivity())
            .setTitle(preference.dialogTitle)
            .setIcon(preference.dialogIcon)
            .setPositiveButton(preference.positiveButtonText, this)
            .setNegativeButton(preference.negativeButtonText, this)
        val contentView = onCreateDialogView(context)
        if (contentView != null) {
            onBindDialogView(contentView)
            builder.setView(contentView)
        } else {
            builder.setMessage(preference.dialogMessage)
        }
        onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder)

        val dialog = builder.create()
        //if (needInputMethod()) {
        //    requestInputMethod(dialog)
        //}
        return dialog
    }

    /* Override the methods that access mWhichButtonClicked (because we cannot set it properly here) */

    /** Which button was clicked.  */
    private var mWhichButtonClicked = 0

    override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
        mWhichButtonClicked = which
    }

    override fun onDismiss(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        onDialogClosedWasCalledFromOnDismiss = true
        super.onDismiss(dialog)
    }

    private var onDialogClosedWasCalledFromOnDismiss = false

    override fun onDialogClosed(positiveResult: Boolean) {
        if (onDialogClosedWasCalledFromOnDismiss) {
            onDialogClosedWasCalledFromOnDismiss = false
            // this means the positiveResult needs to be calculated from our mWhichButtonClicked
            super.onDialogClosed(mWhichButtonClicked == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        } else {
            super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult)
        }
    }
}

fun PreferenceFragmentCompat.showListPreferenceDialog(preference: ListPreference) {
    val dialogFragment = MaterialListPreferenceDialogFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle(1).apply {
            putString("key", preference.key)
        }
    }
    dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0)
    dialogFragment.show(parentFragmentManager, "androidx.preference.PreferenceFragment.DIALOG")
}
```

and then in the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` subclass:

```kotlin
override fun onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference: Preference) {
    if (preference is ListPreference) {
        showListPreferenceDialog(preference)
    } else {
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference)
    }
}
```

Feedback welcome!

Comment: A shame we have to do that

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like adding this to my theme makes the preference dialog appear in material design:

```xml
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
```

At least the font & color are being adapted, the dialog corners however are still not as rounded as the on coming from MaterialAlertDialogBuilder