# How can I customize the UI of ListPreference for PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

I have set my photopreference_layout.xml for PreferenceScreen. 
I  hope to customize the option popup window for  `<ListPreference  android:dialogTitle="@string/Order" ..>`
How can I do?

[image]

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:dialogTitle="@string/DefaultEmail"
    android:key="ToEmail"
    android:summary="@string/DefaultEmailsummary"
    android:title="@string/DefaultEmail"
    android:layout="@layout/photopreference_layout" 
    />

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="Desc"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/Order"
    android:entries="@array/Order"
    android:entryValues="@array/Order_values"
    android:key="SetPhotoOrder"
    android:title="@string/Order"
    android:summary="@string/Ordersummary"        
    android:layout="@layout/photopreference_layout" 
    />
```

**photopreference_layout.xml**

```
<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="@style/myTextAppearance"/>  

<TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="@style/myTextSmall"/>
```

Comment: What exact items do You want to customize?

Comment: Seems this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549746/custom-row-in-a-listpreference provides complete answer.