# ListPreference In SharedPreference

Tags: android, listpreference

I want to ask if its possibile to set for each values/entries in my List, that I can choose them just one time, I mean: I have more ListPreference that use same Values/Entries, if I choose the first values/entries in the first listPreference, I want to disable the first values/entries for other ListPreference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you want to disable some items in `ListPreferences`, this is not supported there out of box. I would recommend to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4557852/1028256) to make a custom `ListPreference` supporting disabled items.

The second issue is that you want to share info about selected items between several `ListPreferences`, for that you need to modify `CustomListPreferenceAdapter` code there to use the same set of data, including info about items selected in all `ListPreferences`. So you probably need to use a `List` where item keeps info about its selection as well (though `Adapter` pattern is designed to abstract from selection being made on ListView side, but in your case you want the selection info to be part of data, huh). And when any `ListPreference` (or a `ListView` too in generic case) makes a selection, you need to notify adapters of other ListPreferences to re-read selection data and disable relevant items.

I'm a bit lazy to write whole code for you )) Use it as a hint.

Comment: I dont want  selection info to be part of my data, just values, Ill try to do what you said. Thank you.