# Custom Row Adapter in androidx.preference.ListPreference

Tags: android, androidx, android-preferences

Legacy ListPreference in Android comes with:

```
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder)
```

That could be use to modify rows in the displayed dialog...
see [custom row in a listPreference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549746/custom-row-in-a-listpreference)

This method is not available anymore in the androidx.preference library
wondering how to achieve  rows customization in the displayed dialog when using androidx.preference support library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should override `PreferenceFragmentCompat#onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference: Preference)` to display a custom preference dialog :

```
override fun onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference: Preference) {
    if (preference.key == MY_CUSTOM_DIALOG_KEY) {
        if (parentFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG) != null) {
            // already displayed to user
            return
        }
        MyCustomPreferenceDialogFragment.newInstance(preference.key).let {
            it.setTargetFragment(this, 0)
            it.show(parentFragmentManager, DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG)
        }
    } else {
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference)
    }
}
```

To implement your custom preference dialog fragment, you can have a look at implementations from support library :

- PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat